# Performing aggregate function on a date range

Tags: sql, scala, dataframe, hive, apache-spark-sql

How to perform an aggregate function (AVG) on a date range

Source data looks like:

```
AccNo   Amt     Date    
1       100     2/1/2021
1       200     2/5/2021
1       300     3/3/2021
2       400     5/20/2021
2       500     5/18/2021
```

The target needs to be derived in the following method:

Ex: To derive `avg_past_week` calculate the average amount for all the rows that are within the date range `Date` to `Date - 7`

Similarily, for `avg_past_month`, it'll be `Date` to `Date - 30`

Target:

```
AccNo   Amt     Date        Avg_past_week   Avg_past_month  Avg_past_3 month
1       100     2/1/2021    100             100             100
1       200     2/5/2021    150             150             150
1       300     3/3/2021    300             250             200
2       400     5/20/2021   450             450             450
2       500     5/18/2021   500             500             500
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.AccNo, a.Amt, a.Date,
  avg(b.Amt) as Amt7,
  avg(c.Amt) as Amt30,
  avg(d.Amt) as Amt90
 from T a 
  join T b on a.AccNo = b.AccNo and b.Date > DateAdd(day, -7, a.Date) and b.date <= a.Date
   join T c on a.AccNo = c.AccNo and c.Date > DateAdd(day, -30, a.Date) and c.date <= a.Date
   join T d on a.AccNo = d.AccNo and d.Date > DateAdd(day, -90, a.Date) and d.date <= a.Date
group by a.AccNo, a.Amt, a.Date
```

result

```
1   100 2021-02-01  100 100 100
1   200 2021-02-05  150 150 150
1   300 2021-03-03  300 250 200
2   400 2021-05-20  450 450 450
2   500 2021-05-18  500 500 500
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have a good volume of data. This causes a performance issue. Any way we can use the windows functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(amt) over (partition by accNo
                      order by datediff('2000-01-01', date)
                      range between 6 preceding and current row
                     ) as avg_7day,
       avg(amt) over (partition by accNo
                      order by datediff('2000-01-01', date)
                      range between 30 preceding and current row
                     ) as avg_30day,
       avg(amt) over (partition by accNo
                      order by datediff('2000-01-01', date)
                      range between 90 preceding and current row
                     ) as avg_91day
from t;
```

This converts the date to a number (number of days since some arbitrary date) and then uses a window frame for the time period.

Note that the number of days going back is one less than the period, because the current day is included as well.